# how can I know if I am connected to carplay on chevrolet car

Tags: ios, carplay

I am using the following method to receive notification from system when connected to Ford car's carplay:

1. NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.EAAccessoryDidConnect
2. Add info.plist key

   Supported external accessory protocols

   com.smartdevicelink.prot29

But I can not receive notification when using Chevrolet carplay and dont know chevrolet info.plist should add what key?

Any help would be appreicate!

Answer (score 1):

- Add corresponding record to your project's Entitlements file
- Make your appdelegate confirm to **CPApplicationDelegate** and
  implement following instance methods

  [application(_:didDisconnectCarInterfaceController:from:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpapplicationdelegate/2968288-application)
  Tells the app delegate that the app disconnected from the CarPlay interface.

  [application(_:didConnectCarInterfaceController:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpapplicationdelegate/2968287-application)
  Tells the app delegate that the app connected to the CarPlay interface.

Find more information on various other monitoring events [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpapplicationdelegate)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But CPApplicationDelegate is used for navigation app, my app is not a navigation type app. And also, I can receive the notify on Ford car after adding key like com.smartdevicelink.prot29 to info.plist. But on Chevrolet car, I don't know add what key, so cant receive notification.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it yet ?